# If the IE browser is not working , Is there any way to retrieve all book mark links which was under favorite folder

Tags: browser

IE-7 browser is not working on my computer and I had long list of web links stored as book mark under favorite folder..I am not sure how I can retrieve it back ?

Answer (score 1):

%system drive%\C:\Documents and Settings\%user% is where you can find your Favorites folder.

Answer (score 0):

go to %userprofile% and see the Favorite folder